# Why the loss of first epoch greater than one in tensorflow when use pearsonr as loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pearson-correlation

I want to use pearsonr as loss function in my DNN network, I followed the scipy.stats.pearsonr to write my own loss function, and it gets the same result as scipy. Heres my func and the result it get

```
def correlationLoss2(x, y):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    y = math_ops.cast(y, x.dtype)
    xmean = tf.reduce_mean(x)
    ymean = tf.reduce_mean(y)
    xsqsum = tf.reduce_sum( tf.math.squared_difference(x, xmean))
    ysqsum = tf.reduce_sum( tf.math.squared_difference(y, ymean))
    cov = tf.reduce_sum( (x - xmean) * (y - ymean))
    corr = cov / tf.sqrt(xsqsum * ysqsum)
    return - corr

x = data[:, 22]
y = data[:, -1]

print(- float(correlationLoss(x, y)))
print(stats.pearsonr(x, y)[0])
```

ignore x and y, they are the dataset of my project, and heres the result:

```
-0.017431042527298025
-0.017431042527298084
```

Things seem to be all right, but when it comes to my network, the first epoch says(my metric func is (1 - corr)):

```
Epoch 1/50
196/196 [==============================] - 35s 172ms/step - loss: 1.0501 - correlationMetric: 0.8766 - val_loss: -0.0295 - val_correlationMetric: 0.9123
Epoch 2/50
196/196 [==============================] - 11s 55ms/step - loss: -0.1150 - correlationMetric: 0.8465 - val_loss: -0.0598 - val_correlationMetric: 0.9115
Epoch 3/50
196/196 [==============================] - 11s 56ms/step - loss: -0.1299 - correlationMetric: 0.8352 - val_loss: -0.0674 - val_correlationMetric: 0.9061
Epoch 4/50
196/196 [==============================] - 10s 53ms/step - loss: -0.1383 - correlationMetric: 0.8270 - val_loss: -0.0734 - val_correlationMetric: 0.9013
```

The result of network is great, but I still wonder why the loss of first epoch is greater than one, that does not make sense. Heres my network:

```
def get_model():
    features_inputs = tf.keras.Input((Config.input_size, ), dtype=tf.float32)

    gn = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.035)(features_inputs)
    feature_x = layers.Dense(256, activation='swish')(gn)
    feature_x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(feature_x)

    feature_x = layers.Dense(512, activation='swish', kernel_regularizer="l2")(feature_x)
    feature_x = layers.Dropout(0.44)(feature_x)
    feature_x = layers.Dense(128, activation='swish', kernel_regularizer="l2")(feature_x)
    feature_x = layers.Dropout(0.33)(feature_x)
    feature_x = layers.Dense(32, activation='swish', kernel_regularizer="l2")(feature_x)
    feature_x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(feature_x)
    output = layers.Dense(1)(feature_x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[features_inputs], outputs=[output])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss=correlationLoss2,
                  metrics=[correlationMetric])

    return model
```

Comment: Try adding `axis=0` to all the `tf.reduce_mean` and `tf.reduce_sum` in your `correlationLoss2`

Comment: but my loss function already gets the same result as scipy.stats.pearsonr

Comment: Then it may be the errors due to floating point arithmetic precision adding up

Comment: that does not make sense... the loss of first epoch won`t even reach one

Comment: What do you mean by loss of first epoch won't even reach 1? The log says that `loss: 1.0501` for the first epoch right? Also, do you use sample weights when fitting?

Comment: When you put any inputs into a pearsonr function, the result will be [-1, 1]. Heres my fit code, im not sure if theres any weight `checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(f"{config.output_dataset_path}model.tf", monitor="correlationMetric", mode="min", save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
        early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)
        history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=50, validation_data=valid_ds, callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop])`

Comment: I don't know how `train_ds` is constructed so can't comment on the sample weights. About pearsonr function always returning [-1,1]: theoretically, yes, numerically, may be no, due to the limited [precision of floating point](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). However, for the floating point errors to build up this much is pretty unlikely.

Comment: but when I turn the lr to lower, the loss reaches 4 or 5, is this still influenced by sample weight?

Comment: Ok, then that's most likely because of your loss function not returning one value for each sample in a batch, but one single value for the entire batch.